# Deployment Failed "Ownable" is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed

Tags: truffle

**"Ownable" is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed.**

- Import abstractions into the '.sol' file that uses them instead of deploying them separately.
- Contracts that inherit an abstraction must implement all its method signatures exactly.
- A contract that only implements part of an inherited abstraction is also considered abstract.
  **This is my Migrations file.**

```
var Ownable = artifacts.require("./@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol");
var Killable = artifacts.require("./zeppelin/lifecycle/Killable.sol");
var Authentication = artifacts.require("./Authentication.sol");
var Rideshare = artifacts.require("./Rideshare.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Ownable);
  deployer.link(Ownable, Killable);
  deployer.deploy(Killable);
  deployer.link(Killable, Authentication);
  deployer.deploy(Authentication);
  deployer.link(Killable, Rideshare);
  deployer.deploy(Rideshare);
};
```

Plese guide me

Answer (score 1):

The contract `Ownable` is abstract (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) which means that you can deploy it on its own. Abstract contracts are meant to be inherited.

So you need to inherit the `Ownable` contract in your own contract and then use its functionality.